# Adding RequiredFieldValidator runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have a ASP.NET usercontrol ( a sign-up form ), and I need to add a requiredFieldValidator runtime. However, it's not working.
Here is how I add the validator.

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.RequiredFieldValidator nameValidator = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.RequiredFieldValidator();
nameValidator.ControlToValidate = "SignUpName";
nameValidator.ErrorMessage = "You must provide your name";
nameValidator.ID = "nameValidator";
nameValidator.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic;
this.Page.Validators.Add(nameValidator);
```

What am I missing?

-------- EDIT ---------

I never found a solution for this. I achieved my goal by using a CustomValidator and doing all the validation manually.

Comment: I'm not a WebForms expert, but it would help others if you tell where are you calling this code from. Page_Load? Button Click? OnInit?

Comment: Called on Page_Load. I'm not sure that's the right thing to do either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are adding controls including validators dynamically then you need to add them on Page_Init not Page_Load otherwise they don't get added to the control tree correctly i.e they don't participate in ViewState

You're probably better using a custom validator rather than dynamically adding a required validator though. Dynamic controls in asp.net have been nothing but trouble for me. I would avoid if there is another solution.

Comment: What if we have to add some controls as well as their validators on button click event?

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try with as below:

Just passing the control id to `ControlToValidate`,

```
nameValidator.ControlToValidate = SignUpName.ClientID; // or SignUpName.UniqueID
```

Comment: None of them work :( Thanks for the suggestion though.
I can achieve my goal by using a CustomValidator control. Not as pretty, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Consider these two things:

- Make the **control to validate** is added to the page control's hierarchy before you add your validator.
- Add your validator to `Page.Controls` not `Page.Validators`