# How to set dynamically textbox required

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was created dynamically text boxes. So it must field by user.
So i want to add something like "RequiredFieldValidator". But I dont know how to add dynamically .User can't go to next step without filling these dynamically text boxes. So how can I control this?

this is my code

```
 for (int i = count; i < no; i++)
                {
                    Label lb = new Label();
                    lb.ID = "lbFname" + NumberOfControls;
                    lb.Text = "First Name :";
                    TextBox tbx = new TextBox();
                    tbx.ID = "Fname" + NumberOfControls;
                    AdultsListPlaceholder.Controls.Add(lb);
                    AdultsListPlaceholder.Controls.Add(tbx);

                    NumberOfControls++;
                    AdultsListPlaceholder.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
                    AdultsListPlaceholder.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
                }
```

any idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464086/adding-requiredfieldvalidator-runtime

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this..

```
RequiredFieldValidator req = new RequiredFieldValidator();
req.ID = "Req" + NumberOfControls;;
req.ControlToValidate = "Fname" + NumberOfControls;;
req.ErrorMessage = "Name Required";
reqfldVal.SetFocusOnError = true;
AdultsListPlaceholder.Controls.Add(req);
```